# google_app_engine runtime process for the instance running on port 46765 has unexpectedly quit

Tags: django, google-app-engine, sympy, digital-ocean

I have successfully installed on Ubuntu digital ocean server but it's automatically close in time interval after 1 or 2 days and need to start again and again on server
i have check process on 8000 port is running but on server 8080 its is not working
error was port close unexpectedly. I am attach Error image so understand you can understand easily.

Error:

```
the runtime process for the instance running on port 46765 has unexpectedly quit

ERROR    2019-11-28 05:52:48,879 base.py:209] Internal Server Error: /input/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/sym_math/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/var/www/html/sym_math/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/middleware/common.py", line 94, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code'
ERROR    2019-11-28 14:25:50,789 base.py:209] Internal Server Error: /input/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/sym_math/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/var/www/html/sym_math/google_appengine/lib/django-1.3/django/middleware/common.py", line 94, in process_response
    if response.status_code == 404:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear to me, is your application failing to run on App Engine or on Digital ocean? Also, at least for App Engine the applications should work on port 8080 otherwise you may need to add a bit of configuration to your app.yaml.

Could you please provide a bit more information regarding the settings of your application and were it's currently failing to run?

Comment: @rsalinas ya my aplication run on Digital Ocean and the major API is called from the App Engine. sometime i run its work properly but in some time thousand of user can request it. it will be error through to  Internal Server Error: /input/
Traceback. but the port is still runing. some other application run that port. how to overcome this type of error

Comment: and the errors you are sharing are from the App Engine Stackdriver logs?

Comment: @rsalinas yes. you have any solution about it?

Comment: I've been doing some looking on your issue and tried to replicate this, can you mention the version of Django you are using?

Comment: @rsalinas  django verstion is->  django==1.3